# Cannot export secret key without providing passphrase

Tags: security, encryption, gnupg, public-key-encryption, gpg-agent

I have forgotten my passphrase for my secret GPG key, and I want to export it, so that I can brute force it with a few likely ones.

However, running `gpg --export-secret-keys` will always make the gpg-agent ask for my passphrase, no matter the options I give to gpg. `--batch`, `--yes`, and `--passphrase-fd` have no effect.

I am running GPG 2.1.15.

I tried exporting a secret key on a machine running GPG 2.0.22 with no troubles. Is it still possible to do this?

If not, my key is lost.

Comment: For anyone else wondering why GPG asks for the passphrase when exporting a secret key, I suppose the reason is the same as for why it asks [when importing it](https://superuser.com/questions/1135812/gpg2-asking-for-passphrase-when-importing-secret-keys) ([see also](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/33183/why-does-gpg-export-secret-keys-ask-for-a-password)).

Answer (score 4):

You can transfer the key "by hand" as follows, without attempting to decrypt it:

```
# create temporary destination dir
mkdir -m 700 /tmp/alt-gnupg
# transfer public keys using export/import, assuming name "user-000"
gpg2 --export user-000 | gpg2 --homedir /tmp/alt-gnupg --import
# transfer private keys using file copy
for g in $(gpg2 --list-keys --with-keygrip --with-colons 'user-000' |
      awk -F: '$1=="grp" {print $10}'); do
    cp ~/.gnupg/private-keys-v1.d/$g.key /tmp/alt-gnupg/private-keys-v1.d
done
# check you got them
gpg2 --homedir /tmp/alt-gnupg --list-secret-keys
```

This works because the private keys are stored in files of the form `<keygrip>.key`, and we can find the keygrips without unlocking.

To brute-force the keys:

```
# use alternate gnupg dir
export GNUPGHOME=/tmp/alt-gnupg
# create dummy encrypted file
echo hello |
gpg2 --encrypt --recipient user-000 --armor >/tmp/msg.asc
# tell gpg-agent to accept loopback pinentry
echo allow-loopback-pinentry >${GNUPGHOME}/gpg-agent.conf
# restart gpg-agent
gpg-connect-agent /bye
# and now...
for p in pass1 pass2; do
    gpg2 --batch --pinentry-mode=loopback --passphrase "$p" --quiet --decrypt /tmp/msg.asc >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo "yes!! pass: $p"
done
```

Comment: Is there a way to export in the OpenPGP format?

Comment: add the --opengpg flag in the appropriate spot